# In class method, difference between [self someMethod] and [[self class] someMethod]

Tags: objective-c

The context is in a class (ie `+`) method, in a (apparently bug-free) method in the superclass implementation of the actual class --

I see

```
something = [self someMethod];
```

and

```
something = [[self class] someMethod];
```

In both cases `someMethod` has an implementation in the "actual" subclass (as well as in the current superclass), and the subclass implementation is what is expected to be invoked.

Is there any practical difference between the two forms, or some reason to prefer one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the difference is that you can safely copy and paste the method anywhere whit [self class]. 
I don't think that there is some other difference.

Comment: I believe you have it!  When I check I see the method with [self class] being invoked in several instance methods, where the `class` is needed.  Presumably the logic was just copied here, or the programmer decided to alway use that style for methods that might be invoked in either context.

Answer (score 1):

There's no practical difference, because `+class` returns the class object, which is exactly what `self` points to in a class method. In other words,

```
+ (BOOL)selfEqualsClassObject {
    return self == [self class];
}
```

will always return `YES`.

Given that, I can't see any reason to prefer sending an extra message. I would say just use `self`.

Comment: Well, to be pedantic, a class *could* override `+class` to return something else, but that would be stupid. In that case, there'd be a difference between the two statements in the question. But it would be dumb to do that and the other explanations are much more likely. ;)

Comment: @KenThomases - Actually, I've thought of a few scenarios where it would sorta make sense to override `class` (though many would consider the approach a perversion).  But nothing so exotic in this case.  I think Guiseppe had the right answer.